# Issue with an expression using the -ing form

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, british-english, spoken-english

What should I know about these two expressions?
I have two expressions but I do not know which one is correct and which one should I use. Above all what is the difference?

1. I am not the one writing the function.
2. I am not who writes the function

And why in the first case we are using the -ing form and also is so strange to see the 'one' followed by that -ing form, what am I missing?

Comment: (1) refers to the function being written, only, and says you are not the one writing it. (2) refers to every function and says you are not the one who writes any of them.

Comment: 2. is ungrammatical. "Who" cannot be used like this in a fused relative construction.

Comment: what do you mean by saying it cannot be used like that? how should i use it?

Comment: thanks , but jhon could you be more precise? I mean, if i had to write as the first example does i am not sure whether i would be really sure that is corrrect or not,

Comment: (2) should be 'I am not _the one_ who writes the function'.

Comment: I am not the one who washes the dishes in this household. Present simple for generalizations. So, your 2) doesn't work even if you fix the grammar.